# How can I dynamically write to different folders in Camel using the header value?

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

I need to transfer files to multiple target systems.
These target systems are defined in the file name from the source system.

For example:

```
SLPNPM_ID0001_T20190329000000.DAT -> target directory : /SLPNPM/
SLPNP1_ID0001_T20190329000001.DAT -> target directory : /SLPNP1/
SLPNP2_ID0002_T20190329000002.DAT -> target directory : /SLPNP2/
...                                   ...
```

So, I implemented below code.

CamelContext.xml

```
    <route id="_route1">
      <from id="_from1" uri="direct:source"/>
      <bean id="_setTarget" ref="setTarget"/>
      <to id="_to1" uri="file:C:/{${header.targetNeId}}/outputFolder"/>
    </route>
    <bean id="setTarget" class="com.ktds.openmzn.sample.SetTarget"/>
```

SetTarget.java

```
    public class SetTarget implements Processor {
     Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SetTarget.class);
     @Override
     public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

    String target_neid = exchange.getIn().getHeader("CamelFileName").toString().substring(0, 6);
        //SLPNPM_FGIDRO01_ID0001_T20190312000500.DAT
        logger.info("Target Ne Id ::: " + target_neid);
        exchange.getIn().setHeader("targetNeId", target_neid);
     }

    }
```

Error Log

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid directory: C:/{${header.targetNeId}}/outputFolder. Dynamic expressions with ${ } placeholders is not allowed. Use the fileName option to set the dynamic expression.
at org.apache.camel.component.file.FileComponent.buildFileEndpoint(FileComponent.java:57) ~[camel-core-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileComponent.createEndpoint(GenericFileComponent.java:56) ~[camel-core-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileComponent.createEndpoint(GenericFileComponent.java:38) ~[camel-core-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponent.createEndpoint(DefaultComponent.java:126) ~[camel-core-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:706) ~[camel-core-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
... 39 common frames omitted
```

How do I handle it if I want to meet my business requirements?

Comment: How are you getting files into that route?  Are they being sent to this route in sequence (e.g. a splitter which scanned the source directory is sending these files along to this route)?

Comment: I found it. Thank you.